Retrieve Quarter/time from pine script request.financial()
I want to create a table with last 5-8 quarter financial data of a script and plot them as a table on the charts. I'm able to retrieve the financial data using the request.financial() method, but how do I know which quarter does it represent to be able to plot it in a table?
Example:
ebitda = request.financial(syminfo.tickerid, "EBITDA", "FQ", gaps=barmerge.gaps_off)
This returns the EBITDA data for the script in a series. But how do I know which quarter does it belong to?
I want the data to look like below but with an added column as quarter?
enter image description here
Is there a way to map the quarter this data belong to in the script?
